# Non-repeating chord progression in pop verse progression

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, pop-music

I am having trouble understanding a pop song verse progression that I came across.

Please see the following screenshot of the sheet music:

[image]

Here are the two main things I notice:

1) The first "phrase" (Am F F/E Am7 Cmaj7 Em) is harmonically more dense than the latter (Am F C Em); and

2) These are two different chord progressions played back to back in the same verse--yet they are not different sections.

I love the way it sounds and I am wondering if this has a name or if there is any theory that indicates how to construct such a chord progression.  Do the nuances of the "first" progression have any harmonic function in terms of leading us to the "second"?

Any insight on this progression is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these would be called passing chords. The first verse is Am F F/E Am7 Cmaj7 Em, and it contains Am F C Em. So I think the main progression would be Am F C Em, and the first verse is just adding a little and varying the harmonic rhythm to create more movement (i.e. by adding F/E and Am7 between the F and C chords).